# Python: item for item until stopterm in item?

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to python!

If I want all the lines of a file until (edit: and including) the line containing some string `stopterm`, is there a way of using the list syntax for it? I was hoping there would be something like:

```
usefullines = [line for line in file until stopterm in line]
```

For now, I've got

```
usefullines = []
for line in file:
    usefullines.append(line)
    if stopterm in line:
        break
```

It's not the end of the world, but since there rest of Python syntax is so straightforward, I was hoping for a 1 thought->1 Python line mapping.

Comment: Just as a note, it might be worth keeping an eye on PEP 3142 (http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-3142/) - this will make it valid to do ``useful = [line for line in file while stopterm not in line]``, solving this neatly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from itertools import takewhile
usefullines = takewhile(lambda x: not re.search(stopterm, x), lines)

from itertools import takewhile
usefullines = takewhile(lambda x: stopterm not in x, lines)
```

Here's a way that keeps the stopterm line:

```
def useful_lines(lines, stopterm):
    for line in lines:
        if stopterm in line:
            yield line
            break
        yield line

usefullines = useful_lines(lines, stopterm)
# or...
for line in useful_lines(lines, stopterm):
    # ... do stuff
    pass
```

Comment: You can use x.find(stopterm) instead if this is just matching a string

Comment: or indeed, stopterm (not) in x as the original question has it.

Comment: Wow, didn't know this one. Of course it exists, it's Python. Silly me. +1

Comment: itertools, operator, and (C)StringIO are the unsung modules of the standard library... everyone should learn them in my opinion. :)

Comment: Wow - I'm just gonna go and delete my re example - thanks for showing me this!

Comment: V. useful, but I'd like the line that includes stopterm, which is admittedly ambiguous in the list syntax version.
Can I retrieve lines.next() after using takewhile?

Comment: Yes, you can use lines.next() after using takewhile. I'll update my example.

Comment: On second thought you lose the stopterm entirely using takewhile. You'll probably want to write a generator function like S. Lott's answer, but one that returns the stopterm line as well.

How irritating of Python. :-|

Comment: An addition is if you what to start when then stat when you can do this:   
linesbetween = takewhile(lambda x: x!=stop_at, list(dropwhile(lambda y: y!=start_at, lines)))

Answer (score 5):

" I was hoping for a 1 thought->1 Python line mapping."  Wouldn't we all love a programming language that somehow mirrored our natural language?

You can achieve that, you just need to define your unique thoughts once.  Then you have the 1:1 mapping you were hoping for.

```
def usefulLines( aFile ):
    for line in aFile:
        yield line
        if line == stopterm:
            break
```

Is pretty much it.

```
for line in usefulLines( aFile ):
    # process a line, knowing it occurs BEFORE stopterm.
```

There are more general approaches.  The `lassevk` answers with `enum_while` and `enum_until` are generalizations of this simple design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

That itertools solution is neat. I have earlier been amazed by itertools.groupby, one handy tool.

But still i was just tinkering if I could do this without itertools. So here it is
(There is one assumption and one drawback though: the file is not huge and its goes for one extra complete iteration over the lines, respectively.)

I created a sample file named "try":

```
hello
world
happy
day
bye
```

once you read the file and have the lines in a variable name lines:

```
lines=open('./try').readlines()
```

then

```
    print [each for each in lines if lines.index(each)<=[lines.index(line) for line in lines if 'happy' in line][0]]
```

gives the result:

```
['hello\n', 'world\n', 'happy\n']
```

and

```
print [each for each in lines if lines.index(each)<=[lines.index(line) for line in lines if 'day' in line][0]]
```

gives the result:

```
['hello\n', 'world\n', 'happy\n', 'day\n']
```

So you got the last line - the stop term line also included.

Answer (score 1):

### Forget this

Leaving the answer, but marking it community. See [Stewen Huwig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28604/steven-huwig)'s answer for the **correct** way to do this.

---

Well, [x for x in enumerable] will run until enumerable doesn't produce data any more, the if-part will simply allow you to filter along the way.

What you can do is add a function, and filter your enumerable through it:

```
def enum_until(source, until_criteria):
    for k in source:
        if until_criteria(k):
            break;
        yield k;

def enum_while(source, while_criteria):
    for k in source:
        if not while_criteria(k):
            break;
        yield k;
    
l1 = [k for k in enum_until(xrange(1, 100000), lambda y: y == 100)];
l2 = [k for k in enum_while(xrange(1, 100000), lambda y: y < 100)];
print l1;
print l2;
```

Of course, it doesn't look as nice as what you wanted...

Comment: That's a lot of work reimplementing the itertools module in the standard library...

Comment: I bet you've had to do this for JavaScript, right? I know I have, in the cases where third-party libraries are not permitted...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine to keep it that way. Sophisticated one-liner are not really pythonic, and since Guido had to put a limit somewhere, I guess this is it...

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [Steven Huwig's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337223/python-item-for-item-until-stopterm-in-item#337285) or [S.Lott's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337223/python-item-for-item-until-stopterm-in-item#337279) solutions for real usage, but as a slightly hacky solution, here's one way to obtain this behaviour:

```
def stop(): raise StopIteration()

usefullines = list(stop() if stopterm in line else line for line in file)
```

It's slightly abusing the fact that anything that raises StopIteration will abort the current iteration (here the generator expression) and uglier to read than your desired syntax, but will work.